# How to get a scratch org in an European data centre?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

When I create scratch orgs, I always get one in US. This is obviously not compliant in the "current climate", nor fast.

I've changed my locale on my DevHub account to no avail.

Comment: Can I know why do you feel its not compliant to current climate? Its scratch org with no customer data. GDPR should be fine.

Comment: I created scratch orgs by specifying a different country(GB and DE) in scratch org config file (Country setting). The orgs were created in CS6 located in APAC

Comment: @ManishG I've tried this myself and orgs were created all over us (O Hare,  PHX, etc). None in APAC (not that I would want to).